# Array bit slicing

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I have an array `[1077:0] tmpVal` which I need to divide into 49 items each of 22 bits width in SystemVerilog.

I did the following, but I'm receiving incorrect values:

```
bit[21:0]   data[49];

for(int i=0; i<49;i++) begin
      j = i+1;
      data[i] = tmpVal[22*j-1 +: 21];
end
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
data[0] - grabs  tmpVal[21:0]
data[1] - grabs  tmpVal[43:22]
...
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi dave_59 - yep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The streaming pack/unpack operator is good for this. You are unpacking a stream of packed 1078 bits into an unpacked chunks of 22 packed bits.

```
module top;
  bit [1077:0] tmpVal;
  bit [21:0]   data[49];
  initial begin
    void'(randomize(tmpVal));
    data = {<<22{tmpVal}};
          
    foreach(data[i])
      $displayh(tmpVal[i*22+:22],, data[i]);
  end
endmodule
```

The `<<22` means stream `tmpVal` from right to left, but keep chunks of 22 bits in the same order. See section *11.4.14 Streaming operators (pack/unpack)* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).

And note the way I used the part-select in the `$display` statement. That would have worked in your `for` loop assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st time through the `for` loop, i=0 and j=1, so `22*j-1` is 21.  But, you want the 1st index to be 0.

You should simply use `i`, and the increment should also be 22:

```
for (int i=0; i<49; i++) begin
    data[i] = tmpVal[22*i +: 22];
end
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.5.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*.